# How to download large file chunk by chunk in .net core Api

Tags: c#, download, angular8, asp.net-core-2.0, filestream

I am currently downloading file using

```
return File(byteArray, filetype, filename);
```

But this is not a solution for downloading large files above 500 MB or 2 GB. I need to stream file in chunk by chunk fashion. Please show me angular8 + .net core 2.1 Api example.

Comment: Why are you passing a byte array to the `File` method? You should pass the file path or a stream so you're not loading it into memory all at once

Comment: Hi Shridhar, Did you find any solution? I am also facing similar issue

Comment: @Vignesh, not yet. I have seen examples in .net MVC. But could find similar solution in .net core + angular.